# Sharing functions among Vue.js components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my application, I have a lot of utility functions that do little things from parsing strings to making toasts and so on. My question is how do I access these in other `.vue` files? I don't want to rewrite these functions for every new Vue component that I write.  Will I be able to use these by importing one component into another? (Vue complains if I don't add the component in the template of another, meaning I can't just import that JavaScript).  If so, is that a good/sensible thing to do? What's the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could create  plugin that exposes the functions on `Vue`. [Plugins documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin)

```
// group utils functions together 
Vue.prototype.$utils = {
    funcA: function () {  ...  },
    funcB: function () {  ...  }
}
```

or

Move them all to common utilities module, `src/utils.js`, then each Vue component can import as needed:

```
// src/utils.js
const funcA = () => {
    console.log('funcA');
}

const funcB = () => {
    console.log('funcB');
}

export { funcA, funcB }

// VueComponentA.vue
import { funcA } from 'path/to/utils';

// VueComponentB.vue
import { funcB } from 'path/to/utils';
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mixins** is a concept you can try.

1. import the component which you need.
2. add mixin array as below in your component just above the data section (or wherever possible)

   mixins:[yourimportedcomponent],
   data:....
3. Call the method you want using **this.theMethodYouWant();**

More you can find it here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html